# Using .properties Resource File ResourceBundle in an XPage

Tags: attributes, xpages, properties-file, resourcebundle

We have data that is fairly static, and we load that data into an XPage for attributes or label names or combo/radio/pull-down dataValues. 
Using Resource Files in the Resources section is fast and simple EL syntax.
But how to dynamically update the data in the Resource File became the challenge. This is how we gotter' done:

First, accessing a Resource File containing manually pasted key=value,[n]; paired-data, just to prove we can; we did like this:
[image: Location of Resource File]

```
<xp:this.resources>
    <xp:bundle src="/dojoPivotData.properties" var="dojoPivotProperties"></xp:bundle>
</xp:this.resources>
```

**The data in the 'dojoPivotProperties.properties' file looks like this:**

[image: Destination Trade Name]

**Passing the variable name `var="dojoPivotProperites"` into a Custom Property of a CustomControl is done by changing the `Type:` of the Property Definition of the property by Pasting `java.util.PropertyResourceBundle` into the Type: property, like so:**
[image]

**And passing in the Resource `var` variable name to the Custom Property where the Custom Control in embedded looks like this:**
[image: Passed to a Custom Property]

**How I used values from the Custom Property, defined in the Custom Control:**
[image]

**How is used the `.properties` file to find keys to get their values to use in repeat controls by doing computations on the value of the passed in `.property` file in a `DataContext`:**
[image]

**To get the Finále where the data is driving the design elements that get generated in the UI:**
[image]

**

- Special Note

**
**The voyages associated with each Destination cell above is generated at load by using the same `java.util.ResourceBundle` .property file to grab each Destination keyName from the `.properties` file. Each keyName in the `.properties` file has a list of voyages associated with that keyName like so**:
[image: Trade Destination keyName's voyages]

**And those voyages associated with `Africa` are generated into an attribute-list for "Africa" square like this:**
[image]

**To get this HTML result in the browser:**
[image]

**Question**: How do we load the keyName=Value pairs into the Resource File on the Fly?

**Ans**: See* "Dynamic .property Resources File on the Fly"
I will show how I did it in a post by that title