# XPages Make Dynamic .property Resources File on the Fly using JAVA with UTF-8 output

Tags: base64, xpages, resourcebundle, ibm-doors, application.properties

This post is a carryover from a previous [Using .properties Resource File ResourceBundle in an XPage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48591870/using-properties-resource-file-resourcebundle-in-an-xpage).  All Kudos goes to  Sean Cullm, Matt White,
Julian Robichaus in this post [Creating an Xpage resource file via DXL without a temporary file](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Creating_an_Xpage_resource_file_via_DXL_without_a_temporary_file) using LotusScript.
     I ran into the error:  `**Base64 byte stream contains invalid data or is too large to store in a single note item**` with some of the key:value pairs being realllly big. To get around the problem of having strings chopped or the error above thrown, I shifted over a JAVA solution to solve what seems to be a LotusScript problem.
Java Solution:
[image]

**JavaAgent extends AgentBase**:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.util.Vector;

import lotus.domino.AgentBase;
import lotus.domino.AgentContext;
import lotus.domino.Database;
import lotus.domino.DateTime;
import lotus.domino.DxlImporter;
import lotus.domino.Log;
import lotus.domino.NotesException;
import lotus.domino.Session;
import lotus.domino.Stream;
import lotus.domino.View;
import lotus.domino.ViewEntry;
import lotus.domino.ViewEntryCollection;

public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {
    public Database db;
    public View view;
    static DxlImporter importer = null;
    Log log;
    DateTime dt;

    public void NotesMain() {

    try {
        Session session = getSession();
        AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();
        // Document contextDoc = agentContext.getDocumentContext();

        log = session.createLog("Agent Log");
        log.openAgentLog();

        this.db = agentContext.getCurrentDatabase();
        this.view = db.getView("dojoprivotdatadocs");

        importer = session.createDxlImporter();
        importer.setReplaceDbProperties(true);
        importer.setReplicaRequiredForReplaceOrUpdate(false);
        importer.setAclImportOption(DxlImporter.DXLIMPORTOPTION_IGNORE);
        importer
            .setDesignImportOption(DxlImporter.DXLIMPORTOPTION_REPLACE_ELSE_CREATE);
        importer
            .setDocumentImportOption(DxlImporter.DXLIMPORTOPTION_IGNORE);
        // importer.importDxl(generateDXL("", "", db.getReplicaID()), db);
        importer.importDxl(generateDXL("", "", ""), db);
        view.setAutoUpdate(true);
        view.recycle();
        db.recycle();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("end__" + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
        System.out.println(importer.getLog());
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("final: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    }

    public Stream generateDXL(String data, final String libName,
        final String dbReplicaId) throws NotesException {
    Session session = getSession();
    Stream dxlStream = session.createStream();
//NOTE: I left the raw DXL generated by an NotesNoteCollection export
//the import DXL is not verbose like the exported DXL, the DXL exported is commented out
    try {
        this.view.refresh();
        this.view.setAutoUpdate(false);
        dxlStream.writeText("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>");
        dxlStream
            .writeText("<!DOCTYPE database SYSTEM 'xmlschemas/domino_9_0_1.dtd'>");
        /**
         * dxl .append("<database xmlns='http://www.lotus.com/dxl' version='9.0' maintenanceversion='1.0' replicaid='"
         * + dbReplicaId +"' path='CN=dom001/OU=SERVER/O=PC!!SSH\\ESA\\PolarColFileData.nsf' title='Polar Col File Data'>"
         * );
         **/
        dxlStream
            .writeText("<database xmlns='http://www.lotus.com/dxl' replicaid='882580D6006A6F64'>");
        /**
         * dxl .append("<fileresource name='base64.properties' noreplace='false' publicaccess='false' designerversion='9.0.1'>"
         * );
         **/
        dxlStream
            .writeText("<fileresource name='dojoPivotData.properties' noreplace='false' publicaccess='false' charset='ISO-8859-1'>");
        // dxlStream
        // .writeText("<created><datetime dst='true'>20171214T101814,59-07</datetime></created>");
        dxlStream.writeText("<filedata>");

        // Base64 base64 = new Base64();
        dxlStream.writeText(Base64.encode(getViewEntires().readText()));
        dxlStream.writeText("</filedata></fileresource></database>");

    } catch (NotesException ne) {
        ne.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("generateDXL:: " + ne.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("generateDXL:: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return dxlStream;

    }

    public Stream getViewEntires() throws NotesException {
    Stream base64Stream = getSession().createStream();
    String eString = "";
    try {
        ViewEntryCollection vec = this.view.getAllEntries();
        ViewEntry tmpentry;
        ViewEntry entry = vec.getFirstEntry();

        while (entry != null) {
        Vector colvals = entry.getColumnValues();
        base64Stream
            .writeText(colvals.get(0).toString(), Stream.EOL_CR);
        tmpentry = vec.getNextEntry();
        entry.recycle();
        entry = tmpentry;
        }
        dt = getSession().createDateTime("Today");
        dt.setNow();
        base64Stream.writeText("@generated=" + dt.getDateOnly() + " "
            + dt.getTimeOnly() + " TZ:" + dt.getTimeZone(),
            Stream.EOL_CR);
        dt.recycle();
        base64Stream.setPosition(0);

    } catch (NotesException ne) {
        ne.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("getViewEntires:: " + eString + ": "
            + ne.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("getViewEntires:: " + eString + ": "
            + e.getMessage());
    }
    return base64Stream;
    }

    /**
     * converts a integer to a byte array in little endian order
     * 
     * @param i
     *            integer to convert
     * @return byte array
     */
    static byte[] toBytes(final int i) {
    ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
    b.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    b.putInt(i);
    return b.array();
    }
}
```

Ascii.java

```
/*
 *  Copyright IBM Corp. 2012-2013
 * 
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); 
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License. 
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at:
 * 
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 
 * 
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software 
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, 
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or 
 * implied. See the License for the specific language governing 
 * permissions and limitations under the License.
 */

/**
 * Ascii constants.
 * <p>
 * Some useful constants.
 * </p>
 * 
 * @ibm-not-published
 */
public interface Ascii {

    public static final byte CASE_OFFSET = 32;

    public static final byte A = 65;
    public static final byte B = 66;
    public static final byte C = 67;
    public static final byte D = 68;
    public static final byte E = 69;
    public static final byte F = 70;
    public static final byte G = 71;
    public static final byte H = 72;
    public static final byte I = 73;
    public static final byte J = 74;
    public static final byte K = 75;
    public static final byte L = 76;
    public static final byte M = 77;
    public static final byte N = 78;
    public static final byte O = 79;
    public static final byte P = 80;
    public static final byte Q = 81;
    public static final byte R = 82;
    public static final byte S = 83;
    public static final byte T = 84;
    public static final byte U = 85;
    public static final byte V = 86;
    public static final byte W = 87;
    public static final byte X = 88;
    public static final byte Y = 89;
    public static final byte Z = 90;

    public static final byte a = 97;
    public static final byte b = 98;
    public static final byte c = 99;
    public static final byte d = 100;
    public static final byte e = 101;
    public static final byte f = 102;
    public static final byte g = 103;
    public static final byte h = 104;
    public static final byte i = 105;
    public static final byte j = 106;
    public static final byte k = 107;
    public static final byte l = 108;
    public static final byte m = 109;
    public static final byte n = 110;
    public static final byte o = 111;
    public static final byte p = 112;
    public static final byte q = 113;
    public static final byte r = 114;
    public static final byte s = 115;
    public static final byte t = 116;
    public static final byte u = 117;
    public static final byte v = 118;
    public static final byte w = 119;
    public static final byte x = 120;
    public static final byte y = 121;
    public static final byte z = 122;

    public static final byte ZERO = 48;
    public static final byte ONE = 49;
    public static final byte TWO = 50;
    public static final byte THREE = 51;
    public static final byte FOUR = 52;
    public static final byte FIVE = 53;
    public static final byte SIX = 54;
    public static final byte SEVEN = 55;
    public static final byte EIGHT = 56;
    public static final byte NINE = 57;

    public static final byte TAB = 9;
    public static final byte LF = 10;
    public static final byte FF = 12;
    public static final byte CR = 13;

    public static final byte SPACE = 32;
    public static final byte PERIOD = 46;
    public static final byte SLASH = 47;
    public static final byte BACK_SLASH = 92;
    public static final byte COLON = 58;
    public static final byte SEMICOLON = 59;
    public static final byte EQUALS = 61;
    public static final byte QUOTE = 34;
    public static final byte LT = 60;
    public static final byte GT = 62;
    public static final byte OP = 40;
    public static final byte CP = 41;
    public static final byte AT = 64;
    public static final byte UNDERSCORE = 95;
    public static final byte STAR = 42;
    public static final byte PERCENT = 37;
    public static final byte HYPHEN = 45;
    public static final byte PLUS = 43;
    public static final byte OPEN_CURLY = 123;
    public static final byte CLOSE_CURLY = 125;
    public static final byte OPEN_ANGLE = 60;
    public static final byte CLOSE_ANGLE = 62;

    /** The CR/LF pair. */
    public static final byte[] CRLF = { CR, LF };
}
```

**Base64OutputStream.java**

```
/*
 *  Copyright IBM Corp. 2012-2013
 * 
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); 
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License. 
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at:
 * 
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 
 * 
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software 
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, 
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or 
 * implied. See the License for the specific language governing 
 * permissions and limitations under the License.
 */

import java.io.FilterOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

/**
 * A Base64 content transfer encoding filter stream.
 * <p>
 * From RFC 2045, section 6.8:
 * <p>
 * The Base64 Content-Transfer-Encoding is designed to represent arbitrary
 * sequences of octets in a form that need not be humanly readable. The encoding
 * and decoding algorithms are simple, but the encoded data are consistently
 * only about 33 percent larger than the unencoded data.
 * 
 * @ibm-api
 */
public class Base64OutputStream extends FilterOutputStream {

    private final byte[] _buffer;
    private int _buflen;
    private int _count;
    private final int _lineLength;

    /**
     * Default constructor.
     * 
     * @param out
     *            the underlying output stream to encode
     * @pre out != null
     * @post out != null
     */
    public Base64OutputStream(OutputStream out) {
    this(out, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor.
     * 
     * @param out
     *            the underlying output stream to encode
     * @param lineLength
     *            the line length
     * @pre out != null
     * @pre lineLength > 0
     * @post out != null
     */
    public Base64OutputStream(OutputStream out, int lineLength) {
    super(out);
    _buflen = 0;
    _count = 0;
    _buffer = new byte[3];
    _lineLength = lineLength;
    }

    /**
     * Writes the specified byte to this output stream.
     * 
     * @param ch
     *            character to write/encode
     * @throws IOException
     *             IO Exception occurred
     * @pre out != null
     * @post out != null
     */
    public void write(int ch) throws IOException {
    _buffer[_buflen++] = (byte) ch;
    if (_buflen == 3) {
        encode();
        _buflen = 0;
    }
    }

    /**
     * Writes <code>b.length</code> bytes from the specified byte array to this
     * output stream.
     * 
     * @param b
     *            buffer to write/encode
     * @throws IOException
     *             IO Exception occurred
     * @pre out != null
     * @post out != null
     */
    public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
    write(b, 0, b.length);
    }

    /**
     * Writes <code>len</code> bytes from the specified byte array starting at
     * offset <code>off</code> to this output stream.
     * 
     * @param b
     *            buffer to write/encode
     * @param off
     *            offset to start of buffer to write/encode
     * @param len
     *            number of bytes from buffer to write/encode
     * @throws IOException
     *             IO Exception occurred
     * @pre off < b.length
     * @pre off+len < b.length
     * @pre out != null
     * @post out != null
     */
    public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        write(b[off + i]);
    }
    }

    /**
     * Flushes this output stream and forces any buffered output bytes to be
     * written out.
     * 
     * @throws IOException
     *             IO Exception occurred
     * @pre out != null
     * @post _buflen == 0
     */
    public void flush() throws IOException {
    if (_buflen > 0) {
        encode();
        _buflen = 0;
    }
    out.flush();
    }

    /**
     * Closes this output stream and releases any system resources associated
     * with this stream.
     * 
     * @throws IOException
     *             IO Exception occurred
     * @pre out != null
     * @post $none
     */
    public void close() throws IOException {
    flush();
    out.close();
    }

    /**
     * Encode current buffer bytes
     * 
     * @throws IOException
     *             IO Exception occurred
     * @pre out != null
     */

    private void encode() throws IOException {
    if ((_count + 4) > _lineLength) {
        out.write(Ascii.CR);
        out.write(Ascii.LF);
        _count = 0;
    }
    if (_buflen == 1) {
        byte b = _buffer[0];
        int i = 0;
        out.write(IoConstants.B64_SRC_MAP[b >>> 2 & 0x3f]);
        out
            .write(IoConstants.B64_SRC_MAP[(b << 4 & 0x30)
                + (i >>> 4 & 0xf)]);
        out.write(Ascii.EQUALS);
        out.write(Ascii.EQUALS);
    } else if (_buflen == 2) {
        byte b1 = _buffer[0], b2 = _buffer[1];
        int i = 0;
        out.write(IoConstants.B64_SRC_MAP[b1 >>> 2 & 0x3f]);
        out.write(IoConstants.B64_SRC_MAP[(b1 << 4 & 0x30)
            + (b2 >>> 4 & 0xf)]);
        out.write(IoConstants.B64_SRC_MAP[(b2 << 2 & 0x3c)
            + (i >>> 6 & 0x3)]);
        out.write(Ascii.EQUALS);
    } else {
        byte b1 = _buffer[0], b2 = _buffer[1], b3 = _buffer[2];
        out.write(IoConstants.B64_SRC_MAP[b1 >>> 2 & 0x3f]);
        out.write(IoConstants.B64_SRC_MAP[(b1 << 4 & 0x30)
            + (b2 >>> 4 & 0xf)]);
        out.write(IoConstants.B64_SRC_MAP[(b2 << 2 & 0x3c)
            + (b3 >>> 6 & 0x3)]);
        out.write(IoConstants.B64_SRC_MAP[b3 & 0x3f]);
    }
    _count += 4;
    }

}
```

**Base64.java**

```
/*
 *  Copyright IBM Corp. 2012-2013
 * 
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); 
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License. 
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at:
 * 
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 
 * 
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software 
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, 
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or 
 * implied. See the License for the specific language governing 
 * permissions and limitations under the License.
 */

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Encodes and decodes to and from Base64 notation.
 * 
 * @ibm-api
 */
public class Base64 {

    /**
     * Decode a base64 string to an ascii string.
     * 
     * @param base64str
     *            the string to decode
     * @return
     * @ibm-api
     */
    public static String decode(String base64str) {
    try {
        StringInputStream bais = new StringInputStream(base64str);
        Base64.InputStream b64 = new Base64.InputStream(bais);
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        int byt;
        while ((byt = b64.read()) >= 0) {
        buf.append((char) byt);
        }
        return buf.toString();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    }

    /**
     * Encode a string to base64.
     * 
     * @param str
     *            the string to encode
     * @return
     * @ibm-api
     */
    public static String encode(String str) {
    try {
        StringBuidlerOutputStream baos = new StringBuidlerOutputStream(str
            .length() * 3 / 2);
        Base64.OutputStream b64 = new Base64.OutputStream(baos);

        int len = str.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        int c = (str.charAt(i)) & 0x00FF;
        b64.write(c);
        }
        b64.flushBuffer();

        return baos.builder.toString();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    }

    public static class StringInputStream extends java.io.InputStream {

    private final String str;
    private int ptr;

    public StringInputStream(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    public int read() throws IOException {
        if (ptr < str.length()) {
        return str.charAt(ptr++);
        }
        return -1;
    }
    }

    public static class StringBufferOutputStream extends java.io.OutputStream {
    private final StringBuffer buffer;

    public StringBufferOutputStream(int size) {
        this.buffer = new StringBuffer(size);
    }

    public StringBuffer getStringBuffer() {
        return buffer;
    }

    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        buffer.append((char) b);
    }
    }

    public static class StringBuidlerOutputStream extends java.io.OutputStream {
    private final StringBuilder builder;

    public StringBuidlerOutputStream(int size) {
        this.builder = new StringBuilder(size);
    }

    public StringBuilder getStringBuilder() {
        return builder;
    }

    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        builder.append((char) b);
    }
    }

    public static class OutputStream extends Base64OutputStream {
    public OutputStream(java.io.OutputStream out) {
        super(out);
    }

    public void flushBuffer() throws IOException {
        flush();
    }
    }

    public static class InputStream extends Base64InputStream {
    public InputStream(java.io.InputStream in) {
        super(in);
    }
    }
}
```

**Base64InputStream.java**

```
/*
 *  Copyright IBM Corp. 2012-2013
 * 
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); 
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License. 
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at:
 * 
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 
 * 
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software 
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, 
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or 
 * implied. See the License for the specific language governing 
 * permissions and limitations under the License.
 */

import java.io.FilterInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

/**
 * A Base64 content transfer encoding filter stream.
 * <p>
 * From RFC 2045, section 6.8:
 * <p>
 * The Base64 Content-Transfer-Encoding is designed to represent arbitrary
 * sequences of octets in a form that need not be humanly readable. The encoding
 * and decoding algorithms are simple, but the encoded data are consistently
 * only about 33 percent larger than the unencoded data.
 * 
 * @ibm-api
 */
public class Base64InputStream extends FilterInputStream {

    private final byte[] _buffer;
    private int _buflen;
    private int _index;
    private final byte[] _decodeBuf;

    /**
     * Constructs an input stream that decodes an underlying Base64-encoded
     * stream.
     * 
     * @param in
     *            the Base64-encoded stream
     * @ibm-api
     */
    public Base64InputStream(InputStream in) {
    super(in);
    _buflen = 0;
    _index = 0;
    _decodeBuf = new byte[4];
    _buffer = new byte[3];
    }

    /**
     * Reads the next byte of data from the input stream.
     * 
     * @throws IOException
     *             IO Exception occurred
     * @return next byte in data stream
     */
    public int read() throws IOException {
    if (_index >= _buflen) {
        decode();
        if (_buflen == 0) {
        return -1;
        }
        _index = 0;
    }
    return _buffer[_index++] & 0xFF;
    }

    /**
     * Reads up to len bytes of data from the input stream into an array of
     * bytes.
     * 
     * @param b
     *            buffer to put data
     * @param off
     *            offset to start of buffer
     * @param len
     *            number of bytes from buffer
     * @throws IOException
     *             IO Exception occurred
     * @return number of bytes read
     */
    public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
    try {
        int l = 0;
        for (; l < len; l++) {
        int ch = read();
        if (ch == -1) {
            if (l == 0) {
            return -1;
            } else {
            break;
            }
        }
        b[off + l] = (byte) ch;
        }
        return l;
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        return -1;
    }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of bytes that can be read (or skipped over) from this
     * input stream without blocking by the next caller of a method for this
     * input stream.
     * 
     * @throws IOException
     *             IO Exception occurred
     * @return number of bytes that can be read
     */
    public int available() throws IOException {
    return (in.available() * 3) / 4 + (_buflen - _index);
    }

    /**
     * Decode Base64 encoded buffer
     * 
     * @throws IOException
     *             IO Exception occurred
     */
    private void decode() throws IOException {
    _buflen = 0;

    // Loop until we hit EOF or non-line-termination char
    int ch = Ascii.LF;
    while (ch == Ascii.LF || ch == Ascii.CR) {
        ch = in.read();
        if (ch == -1) {
        return;
        }
    }

    _decodeBuf[0] = (byte) ch;
    int j = 3, l;
    for (int k = 1; (l = in.read(_decodeBuf, k, j)) != j; k += l) {
        if (l == -1) {
        throw new IOException("Base64 encoding error"); // $NLS-Base64InputStream.Base64encodingerror-1$
        }
        j -= l;
    }

    byte b0 = IoConstants.B64_DST_MAP[_decodeBuf[0] & 0xFF];
    byte b2 = IoConstants.B64_DST_MAP[_decodeBuf[1] & 0xFF];
    _buffer[_buflen++] = (byte) (b0 << 2 & 0xfc | b2 >>> 4 & 0x3);
    if (_decodeBuf[2] != Ascii.EQUALS) {
        b0 = b2;
        b2 = IoConstants.B64_DST_MAP[_decodeBuf[2] & 0xFF];
        _buffer[_buflen++] = (byte) (b0 << 4 & 0xf0 | b2 >>> 2 & 0xf);
        if (_decodeBuf[3] != Ascii.EQUALS) {
        byte b1 = b2;
        b2 = IoConstants.B64_DST_MAP[_decodeBuf[3] & 0xFF];
        _buffer[_buflen++] = (byte) (b1 << 6 & 0xc0 | b2 & 0x3f);
        }
    }
    }

}
```

**IoConstants.java**

```
/*
 *  Copyright IBM Corp. 2012-2013
 * 
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); 
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License. 
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at:
 * 
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 
 * 
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software 
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, 
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or 
 * implied. See the License for the specific language governing 
 * permissions and limitations under the License.
 */

/**
 * Useful constants for base64 package.
 * 
 * @ibm-not-published
 */
public class IoConstants {

    /**
     * RFC822 requires that header lines are limited to 998 octets (excluding
     * CRLF)
     */
    public static final int MAX_RFC822_LINE_LENGTH = 998;

    /**
     * RFC 2822 requires that body content lines can never be more than 998
     * octets (excluding CRLF)
     */
    public static final int MAX_RFC2822_LINE_LENGTH = 998;

    /**
     * Map used for Base64 encoding
     */
    public static final char[] B64_SRC_MAP = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F',
        'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S',
        'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f',
        'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's',
        't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5',
        '6', '7', '8', '9', '+', '/' };

    /**
     * Map used for Base64 decoding
     */
    public static final byte[] B64_DST_MAP = new byte[256];

    /**
     * Char array used in decimal to hexidecimal conversion.
     */
    public static final char[] HEX_CHARS = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6',
        '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };

    /** Construct mapping from source to destination maps */
    static {
    for (int i = 0; i < B64_DST_MAP.length; i++) {
        B64_DST_MAP[i] = -1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < B64_SRC_MAP.length; i++) {
        B64_DST_MAP[B64_SRC_MAP[i]] = (byte) i;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You seem to be using Stack Overflow as a blogging platform which it is not intended for. It is a Q&A site (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).